# How to fix this code that loops through the indexes in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to fix this code. At the moment I get this error.

> Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'UInt8.Bound' conform to 'FixedWidthInteger'

and

> Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'UInt8' conform to 'RangeExpression'

Not sure what the errors mean in this context.

```
let v = characteristic.value;

let count = (v?.count)! / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
var array = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
v?.copyBytes(to: &array, count:count * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

let numCharacteristics = (v![0] & 0xf0) >> 4
let numDataPoints = v![0] & 0x0f

for index in 0..<numDataPoints-1 {

  datapoint = v![index] + (v![index+1] << 8)
  datapointArray.append(datapoint!)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data` type is not subscriptable by `UInt8`. Try:

```
for index in 0..<numDataPoints-1 {
      let intIndex = Int(index)
      let datapoint = v![intIndex] + (v![intIndex+1] << 8)
      datapointArray.append(datapoint)
}
```